How can I edit an embedded message with the username of someone who reacted on the embed?
I'm currently trying to make a discord.js bot that updates/edits the latest embedded message created by the bot in a specific channel to display the username of the user who reacted on it in a field on the embed.
Can somebody help me how I can achieve it so that when a user reacts with a thumbs up on that embed, the bot sees that reaction and then updates the latest iteration of the embed created by the command and displays the username in field 1?
I would like a lot of users to be able to react on that embed and then all their names should be listed in field 1. Does anybody know how to do this?
My code for creating the embed looks like this:
I'm using Discord.js v.14 with EmbedBuilder
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isCommand() && interaction.commandName === 'ct') {
    // Get the current date in the CEST timezone
    const currentDate = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Europe/Paris' }));

    // Calculate the next Tuesday, Thursday, Friday, and Sunday in CEST
    const nextTuesday = getNextDayOfWeek(currentDate, 2); // Tuesday is 2
    const nextThursday = getNextDayOfWeek(currentDate, 4); // Thursday is 4
    const nextFriday = getNextDayOfWeek(currentDate, 5); // Friday is 5
    const nextSunday = getNextDayOfWeek(currentDate, 0); // Sunday is 0

    const wochenplanEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor([181, 142, 70])
      .setTitle('**[:newspaper:] ▬▬▬▬ Unser Wochenplan ▬▬▬▬** ')
      .setDescription(
        `Dienstag: <t:${Math.floor(nextTuesday.getTime() / 1000)}:R> / ` +
        `Donnerstag: <t:${Math.floor(nextThursday.getTime() / 1000)}:R>\n` +
        `Freitag: <t:${Math.floor(nextFriday.getTime() / 1000)}:R> / ` +
        `Sonntag: <t:${Math.floor(nextSunday.getTime() / 1000)}:R>`
      )
      .addFields(
        { name: 'Field 1', value: 'This is the value for Field 1' },
        { name: 'Field 2', value: 'This is the value for Field 2' },
        { name: 'Field 3', value: 'This is the value for Field 3', inline: true },
        { name: 'Field 4', value: 'This is the value for Field 4', inline: true },
      )

    try {
      // Send the embedded message
      const sentMessage = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [wochenplanEmbed], fetchReply: true });

      // Store the sent message containing the embed
      latestEmbedMessage = sentMessage;

      // Wait for a short delay
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

      // React to the fetched message with 4 different emojis
      await sentMessage.react('');
      await sentMessage.react('');
      await sentMessage.react('');
      await sentMessage.react('❤️');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  }
});

How I wanted the embed to update and then list the usernames:

Whenever I tried it it was never updating correctly.
I tried it with "messagereactionAdd" but whatever I tried it never updated the embed.
